# On a theorem of Kronecker!

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations, irrational-numbers, diophantine-approximation

Let $\alpha$ be an irrational number and $\beta$ be an arbitrary real number, Prove that there are infinitely many pair of integers $(x,y)$ with $x\in\mathbb{N}$ such that:
$$|x\alpha-y-\beta|<\frac3x$$

---

This theorem is due to polish mathematician Leopold Kronecker.
There is even sharper results by making use of geometry of numbers.

Comment: See if you can find I.Niven's "Numbers: rational and irrational," chapter six is called "Approximation by Rationals" and has a whole bunch of results like this with down-to-earth proofs.

Comment: I saw the book. This question is different from those which considered in the book! Because in this question we have a free real constant $\beta$!

Comment: Your title makes little sense (but your problem is fine)

Comment: I guess the new proof doesn't use pigeonhole principle! Because we miss $\beta$!

Comment: I suppose so!  Tell us what you've tried!  Have you got anywhere in the proof yet?!  Tell us where you got stuck!

Comment: I answered the question. Take a look!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $N$ be an arbitrary natural number. By [Dirichlet's approximation theorem](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_approximation_theorem) there exist two relatively prime integers $p,q$ with $q\gt 2N$ such that,
$$|q\alpha-p|\lt\frac1q$$
Let $Q$ be the integer or one of the integers such that,
$$|Q-q\beta|\le\frac12$$
By using of [Bézout's identity](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity) there exist two integers $x_0,y_0$ such that,
$$px_0-qy_0=Q$$
Because $p,q$ were relatively prime integers. We may suppose that,
$$|x_0|\le\frac12q$$
Because the set $\{px_0:|x_0|\le\frac12q\}$ contains all integers modulo $q$. By now, we have,
$$|q(x_0\alpha-y_0-\beta)|=|x_0(q\alpha-p)+px_0-qy_0-q\beta|=|x_0(q\alpha-p)+Q-q\beta|\le |x_0(q\alpha-p)|+|Q-q\beta|\lt \frac12q\cdot \frac1q+\frac12=1$$
Taking $x=x_0+q$ and $y=y_0+p$ we have $N\lt\frac12q\le|x|\le\frac32q$. So,
$$|x(\alpha-y-\beta)|\le|x_0\alpha-y_0-\beta|+|q\alpha-p|\lt\frac1q+\frac1q=\frac2q\le\frac3{|x|}$$
This proves the theorem!

Comment: I don't see, tight off, how you get gfrom Dirichlet's theorem, which says that for any $N\in\Bbb{N}$ there exists integers $p$ and $q$ such that $1\leq q \leq N$ and $$|q\alpha - p| \leq  \frac{1}{N+1}$$.  How did $q$ get to the denominator in your form?

Comment: We have,$$|q\alpha-p|\lt\frac1N\le\frac1q$$and when $N$ gets bigger so does $q$!